# A right $R$ module $M$ has finitely many submodules iff right $R$ module $M^n$ has finitely many submodules for any positive integer $n$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, free-modules

A right $R$ module $M$ has finitely many submodules iff right $R$ module $M^n$ has finitely many submodules for  any positive integer $n$.

When $M^n$ has finitely many submodules for  any positive integer $n$, then clearly $M$ has finitely many submodules. But, I have failed to prove it's converse. Please help me.

Comment: Completely false. Let $R=\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ has two submodules, while $\mathbb{R}^2$ has infinitely many [each being a line through the origin].

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson thank you.

Comment: @rschwieb Done.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely false. Let $R = \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ has two submodules, while $\mathbb{R}^2$ has infinitely many [namely, all lines through the origin].